# Android emulator force landscape on start-up

Tags: android, android-emulator, landscape-portrait

I have correctly configured application, which runs in landscape only. When I run it on Emulator (v.24.4.0.0), the Android starts in portrait mode. Application runs in landscape, but picture is rotated and header of window is hidden, because in portrait mode emulator does not fit. I can rotate it by <kbd>LeftCTRL + F12</kbd>. Next I can press <kbd>Alt + Space</kbd> a choose Move to show whole window, but it is not nice.

If you could help me to force the default orientation as landscape, you make me happy : )

In Emulator and AVD Manager I don't see any settings, where I could make this preference. Config.ini in my avd directory contains:

```
hw.initialOrientation=landscape
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AVD Manager, use "Edit" button and choose another device, labeled as "tablet", which is landscape by default. Note screen dimensions, where X should be greater than Y.

If none of predefined devices satisfy your needs, you can switch to the "Device definitions" tab of AVD Manager and create your own device. I prefer light screens e.g. 800x480 which are emulating faster. Then use "Create AVD" button to define new emulator instance.

Comment: This is right answer, but I have found just two tablets with landscape, Nexus 9 and Nexus 10. Neither does not work. After very very long boot A.S. cannot copy apk there... I'm giving it up, I'll use physically device or rotate and move window. Thank you!

Comment: Don't give up, I've aded another clue to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Start emulator
2. Open "Settings" app
3. Go to "Display"
4. Turn "Auto-rotation screen" option ON
5. Try to rotate device to landscape mode.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Set orientation on your android mainfest:

```xml
    <activity
        android:name=".Android_mobile_infoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity before setcontentview();

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

paste this...hope this will work..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have fixed orientation for your activities then you can use-

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

as an attribute to that activity in that manifest. But if you want to set the orientation in runtime depending upon what was the previous orientation while launching the application, you need to check for the previous orientation in `onCreate()` and then set it to that value programmatically there itself using `setRequestedOrientation()` in the activity

**Sometimes  emulator doesn't work perfectly, So use real device for accurate result.**